# Wireless print server recommendation

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, printing, network-printer

I'm looking for a wireless print server for home use.

I have the following in place already:

```
2 MacBook Pros (OS X 10.6)
1 Apple Airport Extreme 
1 HP 6L printer (currently connected to a wired HP Jet Direct)
```

The printer uses a Parallel port, not a USB port.

Some changes at home are making the change to wireless necessary.
I cannot use the Airport Extreme as it is in a different room.

Does anyone have a good recommendation for a wireless print server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a parallel printer; not USB, so you could probably try a a USB-to-Parallel adapter and then use a USB print server of your choice.

That might be a bit of a stretch -- but again it might not also be since the 6L is a generic PostScript printer and is probably easy as pie to support.

Answer (score 1):

Would an [Apple Airport Express](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB321LL/A/AirPort-Express-AirTunes) to the trick?